# How to make a button to hide/show a jQuery grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to remove a button that hides and shows a jQuery grid (the one on the right top of the grid). How can I do that?

Comment: some code? HTML or JavaScript... :)

Comment: Where is your [test case](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: If I had the code I would not need to post this question!!!!

Comment: please tag your questions appropriately and take a little bit of time to phrase them properly.

Comment: I think is tagged appropriately and Hamidi understood exactly what I meant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [hidegrid](http://hidegrid) option to `false`:

```
$(selector).jqGrid({
    // ...
    hidegrid: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put a button in the html with id showGrid and then use this

```
$("#showGrid").click(function (e){
       $("#myGrid").jqGrid('setGridState','visible');//or 'hidden' 
       return false; 
});
```